# Handle `<select>` with only one value generated dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dynamically generated `<option> .. </option>` which is inserted into `<select>`

When a case comes where there is only 1 `<option>` value, I dont want the user looking at a combo box with intend to click and expect some more values.

Since there is only one value can i close the activity of the `<select>` to produce Drop Down like deactivating it?

Will this-

`<select disabled="disabled">`

also means that I cant get the variable values upon Form submit by `$_POST` ?

Can i do something using jQuery. I would prefer HTML although.

### edit

Just checked: `<select disabled="disabled">` wont allow Posting form data for `<select>`

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode:

```
switch (number of options)
    case 0:
        display nothing
        break;
    case 1:
        display the option as normal text (maybe in a simple <div>)
        break;
    default:
        create and display a combo box
        break;
```

Don't forget: Jquery is javascript! All you can do in javascript is still allowed.

Comment: Thanks. jQuery is a js, i know. Need to do in a simpler and better way. Last option would be obviously manually managing it, but I would like to know more power which HTML offers.

Comment: And if you need the value to be sent with the form, you can use an `<input type="hidden">`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selected in the only option, than the value will be this option:

```
<select name="data" style=" disabled="disabled">  
     <option value="1" selected>1</option>
</select>
```

with the following code you can check how many options the select has.

```
$('#data1').children().length
```

If the length is 1 add disabled and selected:

```
if($('#data1').children().length == 1) {
     $('#data1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('#data1').children()[0].attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

Hope this helps.